# Multiplication by $n$ formula on elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, elliptic-equations

Let be $E:y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ an elliptic curve, with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}$, and $P=(x,y)\in E$.

I would like to show: $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}\hspace{0.2cm}\exists \phi_n,\psi_n\in\mathbb{Q}[X]: x(nP)=\frac{\phi_n(x)}{\psi_n(x)}$

For that we can use induction. If n=2 we know that it is true due to the duplication formula.

For any $n$ we have $x(nP)=\frac{\phi_n(x,y)}{\psi_n(x,y)}$ because the addition law is given by rational functions.

Moreover we know

$x(nP)=x(-nP)=x(n(x,-y))$, so $\frac{\phi_n(x,y)}{\psi_n(x,y)} = \frac{\phi_n(x,-y)}{\psi_n(x,-y)}$

How can i finish the proof?

Comment: From $x(nP)=x(-nP)$ you have $f_n(x,y)=f_n(x,-y)$ which implies that every power of $y$ must be a square where $f_n=\phi_n/\psi_n$. Now replace $y^2$ with $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$...

Comment: @MattB thank you very much